# MySql Insert with condition

Tags: mysql

Is my request feasible ?

I want to secure the insertion with the password of the admin.

```
INSERT INTO `user` (`id`, `pw`, `name`) VALUES (?,?,?) WHERE EXISTS (select * from `admin` where pw=?)
```

Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear to me at all what this is meant to accomplish.  What do you expect this to do that's different than just a normal `INSERT`?

Comment: Testing someone's admin status by verifying their password on every single SQL operation is extremely risky. This implies that you haven't properly hashed their password, because if you had you'd need to use Bcrypt or Scrypt to verify it, something MySQL doesn't support.

Answer (score 2):

I would tend to write this as:

```
INSERT INTO `user`(`id`, `pw`, `name`)
    SELECT x.id, x.pw, x.name
    FROM (SELECT ? as id, ? as pw, ? as name) x
    WHERE EXISTS (select 1 from `admin` a where a.pw = x.pw);
```

Note that you do not need to include the `pw` parameter twice (I'm assuming that this is the logic you want).

More importantly, you seem to want to be sure that `pw` is properly valid in `admin`.  The real way to do this is with a foreign key constraint:

```
alter table user add constraint fk_user_pw
    foriegn key (pw) references admin(pw);
```

Then you don't need special logic in the `insert`.  It will fail if the `pw` values do not match.

Better yet, this works for `update` as well as `insert`.

Comment: SQL wise you're providing a good answer here, but testing admin status by verifying a password which is presumably plain-text or badly hashed is really a super bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - but you should use the SELECT form of INSERT

```
INSERT INTO `user` (`id`, `pw`, `name`)
 SELECT ?,?,? FROM dual WHERE EXISTS (select * from `admin` where pw=?)
```

Comment: Can you explain reasoning of that change? I am not saying you are wrong but it would be nice knowing beside *what* can we do, *why* should we do it.

Comment: I don't think you can add a WHERE clause to the INSERT ... VALUES statement - but you can have a WHERE clause on the INSERT ... SELECT form. No particular reason for that other than that's the way the language was defined.